# How to use the protractor on versions of a website

Tags: protractor

I need to test two different versions of a website where one has slightly different functionality than the other. As part of this I want to use the same code but depending on the IP address of the site, choose if a test should run or not. Is there a way this can be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make your website and login information included into your conf.js file so that it can be readily changed without modifying large amounts of your code.

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  params: {
    login: {
      username: '*****',
      password: '*****',
    },
    website: {
      url: '*****',
    },
  },
  specs: 'spec.js'
}
```

Then, inside your spec.js file, try the following:

```
// spec.js
describe('General Testing', function() {

  browser.driver.sleep(0).then(function() {
    if(browser.params.website.url == 'www.gmail.com'){
      it('should run this test', function() {
        // **********
      });
    } else {
        it('should run the second test', function() {
          // **********
        });
    }
  });

});
```

EDITED:
I realized afterwards, that your question might be referring more specifically to the ip address rather than a url. I looked through the protractor api, and found no direct way to access the ip. There are only commands like `browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()` and `browser.driver.getTitle()`. I believe you would have to use some sort of extra codebase, to obtain what you desire.

Comment: Hi bdf7kt, This was the direction that I was going to go in. I just though that there might be a different approach that I could use. I have static addresses for both of the websites that I use so it makes it easier for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have two environments you want to test, I would consider simply making two conf files - one for each environment - and separating your spec files into different folders, depending on which environments you want them to run on.

The first config would contain:

```
//env1conf.js
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['./common/*spec.js', './env1/*spec.js'],
  onPrepare: function() {
      browser.get('environment1');
  }
}
```

And the second:

```
//env2conf.js
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['./common/*spec.js', './env2/*spec.js'],
  onPrepare: function() {
      browser.get('environment2');
  }
}
```

In the above example, you would have three folders, (common, env1 and env2) that each contain spec files. You can then run your tests on one or the other environments just by referencing one config or the other when you run protractor:

```
> protractor env1conf
```

(which will run all specs in common and env1 against your environment1 url)

This approach will also make it easier if you want to move tests from one environment to another, or move them into "common" if they become relevant for both. If you ever need a third environment, it would be simple enough to set up a third configuration file.

Note that in the above config files, I've included a `onPrepare` statement that will navigate to the appropriate environment but you could easily use a parameter instead:

```
params: {
        url : 'environment1'
}
```

if you prefer to do the `browser.get` statement in the actual specs:

```
browser.get(browser.params.url);
```